# Is a shortcut and symbolic link the same? If not, how do I create a shortcut?

Tags: command-line, shortcuts, symbolic-link

I found this link on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link
According to them Symlinks are not really shortcuts.

I had the need to create a shortcut to a program on the Desktop and I wanted to do this using a terminal command. I could not find one. Rather I bumped into the **ln** command which does pretty much the same (to my knowledge).

So if it's not the same, how do I create a shortcut?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're similar things, but while a link it's just that, a link to a file or folder, a shortcut can contain more information, like launching parameters, personalized icons, etc.
To create a symbolic link you just need to do in a terminal:

```
ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symboliclink
```

To create shortcuts with personalized options, there's a program called arronax:

```
sudo apt-get install arronax
```

You can create shortcuts, save where you want (usually the desktop or in $HOME/.local/share/applications if you want them to appear in the unity dash), set icons, set if you want to run the program in a terminal or not... etc.

Here's an example:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: I love that short and clear answer. But if shortcuts are such a basic thing, why do we need another program like arronax to do it? Can't we just do it using the terminal?

Comment: You can actually create a shortcut simply with vim or another text editor because they're just plaintext, but I use arronax because I'm not familiarized with the syntax.